# Fundamental Discriminant

Tags: abstract-algebra, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, discriminant

Let $d=2\bmod4$ and $D=d^3-1$. We will show that the elliptic curve $E_D: y^2=x^3+D$ has no integer solutions $x,y$.

At first we show that $x$ is odd which is simple. Then we have the following argument:

$y^2+1=x^3+d^3=(x+d)(x^2-dx+d^2)$. Since $x$ is odd we have $x^2=1\bmod4$ and $dx=2\bmod4$ then $x^2-dx+d^2=3\bmod4$.

Then I cannot understand the following argument:

Discriminant of $x^2-dx+d^2$ is negative so it is divisible by a prime $p=3\bmod4$.

I understand the final argument: so $y^2+1$ is divisible by $p$ then $y^2=-1\bmod4$ but $-1$ is not a square. Contradiction.

Can someone explain me the argument above? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example appears in Silverman's book "Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves".

The argument:

You already know that $x^2 - dx + d^2\equiv 3 \mod 4$. The discriminant argument tells us that $x^2 - dx + d^2$ must be positive. Thus it is a positive odd integer.

It follows that at least one of its prime factor must be $\equiv 3 \mod 4$: otherwise, all of its prime factors would be $\equiv 1\mod 4$, and hence it would also be $\equiv 1\mod 4$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much. It looks like simple but i couldnt see :). I have another question. You said that "the discriminant argument tells us that ... must be positive. Thus it is a positive integer". Do you mean that if discriminant is negative then it has no root so we can take it positive or is there another argument? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is middle school level mathematics: if $a > 0$ and $b^2 - 4ac < 0$, then for any real numbers $x, y$, we have $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: yes of course I know. but I don't know much about this topic and I am trying to learn. I wondered is there another argument related to fundamental discriminant or not. Thank you again :)